# what is wrong with the way I am coding the probability of surviving?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to create a model in which turtles move through a landscape and each type of patch means a different probability of survival for the turtles (representing patches that have more resources = higher chance of survival, patches with less resources = lower chance of survival).
However, all my turtles die out super quickly and don't seem to be following the differences in the probability of survival.
The only thing I have identified is that only if they are in a patch with probability of survival = 1, they survive. If not (even if the probability is .96), they die.
The probability of survival that each type of patch represents is determined by a slider.

```
extensions [
  gis
  palette
]

patches-own [
  TipoRaster
  tipoDeUso 
  **probSupervivencia** 
]

breed [bichos bicho]

to go
  if not any? turtles [stop]
  if ticks = 120 [stop] ;; representa un ciclo de vida de las hembras adultas (donde cada tick = 1 dia). ***180
  ask turtles [
    **move
    if random-float 1.00 > probSupervivencia [die]**
  ]

tick
end

to initHabitat

  if Habitat = "bichos" [
    ask patches with [ tipoDeUso = "Urbano" ][
    set probSupervivencia probabilidad-supervivencia-urbano
  ]
    ask patches with [ tipoDeUso = "Nada" ][
    set probSupervivencia probabilidad-supervivencia-nada
  ]
    ask patches with [ tipoDeUso = "Bosque" ][
    set probSupervivencia probabilidad-supervivencia-bosque
  ]
    ask patches with [ tipoDeUso = "CuerposDeAgua" ][
    set probSupervivencia probabilidad-supervivencia-agua
  ]
    ask patches with [ tipoDeUso = "Pastizal" ][
    set probSupervivencia probabilidad-supervivencia-pastizal
  ]
    if calidad-matriz = "actual" [
    ask patches with [ tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaTemporal" ][
      ifelse random-float 1.00 < 0.32 [ set probSupervivencia probabilidad-supervivencia-agricultura-calidad-baja ][ set probSupervivencia probabilidad-supervivencia-agricultura-calidad-alta ]
    ]
    ask patches with [ tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaRiego" ][
      ifelse random-float 1.00 < 0.63 [ set probSupervivencia probabilidad-supervivencia-agricultura-calidad-baja ][ set probSupervivencia probabilidad-supervivencia-agricultura-calidad-alta ]
    ]
  ]
    if calidad-matriz = "alta" [
    ask patches with [ tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaTemporal" or tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaRiego" ][
      set probSupervivencia probabilidad-supervivencia-agricultura-calidad-alta
    ]
  ]
    if calidad-matriz = "baja" [
    ask patches with [ tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaTemporal" or tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaRiego" ][
      set probSupervivencia probabilidad-supervivencia-agricultura-calidad-baja
    ]
  ]
    if calidad-matriz = "contrastante" [
    ask patches with [ tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaTemporal"][
      set probSupervivencia probabilidad-supervivencia-agricultura-calidad-alta
    ]
    ask patches with [ tipoDeUso = "AgriculturaRiego" ][
      set probSupervivencia probabilidad-supervivencia-agricultura-calidad-baja
    ]
  ]
  ]
end

**to move**
     if random 100 < 10 [move-to one-of patches in-radius (tasa-movimiento / longitud-step)]
end
```

Can anybody figure out what it is I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked (with an `inspect` window) that the patch survival variables are sensible numbers. Try checking `mean`, `max`, `min` etc to be sure they are in the range [0,1]. You may have your sliders with values 0-100 for percentage for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your agents need to inquire about the patch they occupy.

Something like

```
ask turtles [
  if ([probSupervivencia] of patch-here < random-float 1.00) [die]
]
```

Comment: That's unlikely to be the problem because turtles automatically have access to the patch variables of the patch where they are located (that is, `of patch-here` is not needed).  It doesn't work the other way because patch to turtle is not unique.